# InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network

running a CNN model and during prediction it is showing Graph execution error:

```
CODE: test_image = []
for img_name in test.Image_ID:
    img = plt.imread('' + img_name)
    test_image.append(img)
test_img = np.array(test_image)
       
test_image = []
for i in range(0,test_img.shape[0]):
    a = resize(test_img[i], preserve_range=True, output_shape=(224,224)).astype(int)
    test_image.append(a)
test_image = np.array(test_image)


# preprocessing the images
test_image = preprocess_input(test_image, data_format=None)

# extracting features from the images using pretrained model
test_image = base_model.predict(test_image)
test_image.shape



predictions = base_model.predict(test_image)


after this it shows error:
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[34], line 1
----> 1 predictions = base_model.predict(test_image)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb
```

so i dont understand as i was trying to predict the output of the images that it created

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: HI @Harmanjot Could you add the code snippet/python command you are trying to execute in the jupyter notebook and the full stacktrace? I understand that you are struggling to resolve an exception, but cannot analyse the root cause without more detailed information.